# Dynamically creating an array from another array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a dynamic array as input.
From this array I need to create another array.
For example I have an array like below :

```
var InputArr = [{
  "IM_Id": "1",
  "IM_Description": "XXX5",
  "IM_FirstProcessDate": "10-19-2016",
  "IM_Alias": "test",
  "IM_MasterPrice": "$33.00",
  "IM_ProductId": "22001204",
  "IM_ProductDescription": "TEST EP PRODUCT FOR DEVELOPMENT",
  "IM_EPProduct": "yes",
  "ItemMasterNumber": "290015",
  "FS_Id": "2002",
  "FS_Code": "XXX5",
  "FS_Name": "XXX5",
  "FS_Description": "XXX5",
  "FS_EnablementType": "",
  "FS_EPProduct": "yes",
  "CH_Id": "4787",
  "CH_ChargeId": "23004746",
  "CH_Name": "XXX5",
  "CH_Description": "",
  "CH_Type": "One Time",
  "CH_EPProduct": "yes",
  "CA_Id": "1628",
  "CA_ListPrice": "99",
  "CA_FairValueBasis": "BESP",
  "CA_FairValueLow": "99",
  "CA_FairValueHigh": "99",
  "CA_EffectiveStartDate": "04-18-2017",
  "CA_EPProduct": "yes",
  "OF_Id": "3881",
  "OF_OfferId": "20003880",
  "OF_Name": "XXX5",
  "OF_Description": "XXX5",
  "OF_Level": "BASE",
  "OF_Type": "19-APR-2017",
  "OF_EffectiveStartDate": "04-18-2017",
  "OF_EPProduct": "yes"
}]
```

I need to iterate through this array and push the values to a new array but dynamically.
I cant take the parameters again like pushing the values as

```
"IM_Id":val['IM_Id']
```

My code should dynamically consider the keys and their values. This is because the initial input array is dynamically created and might have some additional keys values too.

How should I push these values dynamically to resulting array?
I tried Something like

```
resultingArray.push({InputArrKey1 : 
InputArrayValue2,InputArrKey2:InputArrayValue2});
```

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: You can simply use `arr.push(InputArr[0])`

Comment: `resultingArray.push(InputArr[0]);` done.

Comment: All code is "dynamic". Saying "dynamic" is redundant.